# Get retrive files inside folder inside jar

Tags: java, jar, inputstream, java-web-start, embedded-resource

I'm making a Webstart application where i need to retrive some files laying inside a folder in a jar.
I would need to copy the whole folder with contents to local drive. How do i do it? 
It seems that Webstart only approve inputstreams to read from jar. So the folder must be read as and inputstream somehow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As discussed in the [info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource), you can use [`getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) to obtain a `URL` for each file. This simple [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/googleolympiad) caches images in `getImage()`; this more elaborate [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) constructs image sets in `RCImage`. Both read from a folder named `images` in the JAR file.

Comment: Thank you! I solved it yesterday using zipEntry, searched the whole jar for my files and retrived them.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using zipentry Zipinputstream and FileOutPutStream.

**NOTE:** This only works if you run it outside of Eclipse JVM(for example as in my case running Java Webstart).

```
CodeSource src = MAINCLASS.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource();
                if (src != null) {
                    URL jar = src.getLocation();
                    ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(jar.openStream());
                    ZipEntry e = null;
                    while ((e = zip.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                        System.out.println("Entry name: " + e.getName());
                        if (e.getName().endsWith(".db")) {
                            FileOutputStream outPutFile = new FileOutputStream(folderDest + File.separator
                                    + e.getName().substring(e.getName().indexOf("INSERT-CHAR-WHERE-TO-BEGIN-RETRIVE-FILE -NAME")));
                            int data = 0;
                            while ((data = zip.read()) != -1) {
                                outPutFile.write(data);
                            }
                            outPutFile.close();
                        }
                    }
                    zip.close();
                } else {
                    Log.error("Can't retrive running jar.");
                }
```